# Creating magical spheres for Deities in D&D 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, homebrew, conversion, religions-and-deities

When creating Goddesses and Gods in the past editions of D&D I have chosen the spheres I wanted for them based on what flavor fit for the type of deity I was creating. Not having the separation of the spheres in 3.5 I was wondering if anyone had done that themselves or if there might be a resource out there that had done that type of conversion?

(Yes I googled it, but came up empty)

Comment: By "spheres", you mean [Domains](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/clericDomains.htm)?

Comment: @Adeptus Actually Velthor means "lists of spells that are akin to wizard schools, but called spheres, as in spheres of influence." They were used in AD&D 2e, and perhaps AD&D itself. In those editions, priests of specific mythoi (such as the example given in the PHB, the druid) got their unique spell lists that way. Additionally, regular priests had access to all spheres except plant and weather, plus 3rd level or lower access to elemental.

Comment: @Chemus Yes that is precisely what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Domains are the solution to what you are looking for, but you may want to glance at the *Complete Psionic* Mantles as well, as they cover spells like PHB domain spells on page 185+, but include some additional "spheres" of influence.